# Split the text in paragraphs

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x, nlp

I know that I can use something like this

```
theText='She loves music. Her favorit instrument is the piano.\n\n However, \n\n she does not play it.'
paragraphs = [p for p in theText.split('\n\n') if p]
for i,p in enumerate(paragraphs):
    print(i,p)
```

to split theText in paragraphs.

However, I would like to add an additional conditional that the next sentence cannot start with a lower case letter.
The actual code provides

```
0 She loves music. Her favorit instrument is the piano.
1  However, 
2  she does not play it.
```

I would like

```
0 She loves music. Her favorit instrument is the piano.
1  However, she does not play it.
```

I believe that I should use some regex, but I could not figure out the correct structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex, which ensures that your `\n\n` is followed by a capital letter (and an optional space) using the [Lookahead](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) `?=`. Also, in your enumerate, you'll have to get rid of your `\n\n` (here, using `re.sub`):

```
import re
paragraphs = re.split('\n\n\s?(?=[A-Z])',theText)
for i,p in enumerate(paragraphs):
    print(i,re.sub('\n\n\s?','',p))

0 She loves music. Her favorit instrument is the piano.
1 However, she does not play it.
```

Comment: `re.split(r'\n*',re.sub(r'\n*(?= [a-z])','',theText))`